# How to disable dynamic update in DynamicModule when certain variable is updated

Tags: dynamic

I have a UI with `DynamicModule`s. I have a progress bar, whenever the varibale `progress` updates, the `DynamicModule` reevaluates everything, making the UI extremely slow. Is there a way to disable dynamic updating when a certain variable is updated?
Basically, when the progress bar is updating, I do not want to recalculate everything hundreds of times, but when other variables are updated, I want the DynamicModule to reevaluate.

Comment: have a look at `TrackedSymbols` and possibly also `Refresh`

Comment: I had similar problem, the solution I opted for was actually making my UI faster by using compiled functions. I got the UI evaluation from 7s down to 0.2s. If you are not already doing that, try using Compiled functions and also if you Solve or Minimize for a numerical problem, try replacing them with FindRoot and FindMinimum (not NSolve and NMinimize), these are way faster ...

Comment: To answer your question, we would have to know how your progress bar is coupled to your other dynamic variables -- that is, we need to see your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the part that you want to be updated using `Dynamic`.

Check the difference between these two codes:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{{Gray, 
    Line /@ Partition[RandomReal[{-4, 4}, {1000, 2}], 2]}, {Red, 
    Circle[{a, b}, c]}}], {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, {c, 1, 4}]

Manipulate[
 Graphics[{{Gray, 
    Line /@ Partition[RandomReal[{-4, 4}, {1000, 2}], 2]}, 
   Dynamic@{Red, Circle[{a, b}, c]}}], {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, {c, 1, 
  4}]
```